# How to execute queries in remote servers

Tags: php, mysql-connect

I am trying to insert data to a web site from the code of another web site. How can I use the `mysql_connect()` command for that. Can I use the IP address of the first web site in the second web site code?

Please help me

Comment: How can I accept an answer ? I have clicked in "Useful "

Comment: somebody is trying NAUGHTY stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a remote MySQL server with mysql_connect(). Use mysql_connect() according to the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php) and use your server's IP as $server. However, make sure the MySQL port is accessible from remote on the MySQL server (port 3306).

Answer (score 0):

For inserting data in the database you need to connect the database

[Selecting DATABASE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

you need to just connect the server on which the db exist in which we are inserting

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('ip or server of the db in which inserting', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make myDB the current database 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('myDB', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use myDB: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

for inserting records in another website , you need to just connect the server and DB of that particular website, and fire Queries.

let me know if more..